# Keep focus on input box when click on button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple calculator with 2 inputs, and when I click on button I want to check if one of inputs is focused and if yes to enter that number.

But when I click on button I lose focus on inputs and get it on that button.

```js
let activeElement = document.activeElement;

function numClick(number){
  console.log("Num clicked=" + number);

  let tempNumber="";
  tempNumber = activeElement.value;
  tempNumber = tempNumber + number;
  activeElement.value=tempNumber;

}
```

```html
<input id = "num1" type="text" name="num1" value="">
  <span id="operacija"></span>
  <input id = "num2" type="text" name="num2" value="">
  <span>=</span>
  <span id="rezultat">0</span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="clearIt() "value="C">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('/')"value="/">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(7)" value="7">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(8)" value="8">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(9)" value="9">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('*')"value="*">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(4)" value="4">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(5)" value="5">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(6)" value="6">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('-')"value="-">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(1)" value="1">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(2)" value="2">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(3)" value="3">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('+')" value="+">
  <br>

  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(0)" value="0">
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="=">
  <br>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="zadatak1.js"></script>
```

I am not using any framework, just JS...

Comment: You can't gain the focus on two elements at the same time. Store the last active input to a variable when it gets blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var activeInput = ""
function inputClick(input){
  activeInput = input;
}

function numClick(number){
  document.getElementById(activeInput).value += number;
}
```

```html
<input id="num1" type="text" name="num1" value="" onclick=inputClick('num1')>
<span id="operacija"></span>
<input id="num2" type="text" name="num2" value="" onclick=inputClick('num2')>
<span>=</span>
<span id="rezultat">0</span>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="clearIt() "value="C">
<input type="button" onclick="operationClick('/')"value="/">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(7)" value="7">
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(8)" value="8">
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(9)" value="9">
<input type="button" onclick="operationClick('*')"value="*">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(4)" value="4">
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(5)" value="5">
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(6)" value="6">
<input type="button" onclick="operationClick('-')"value="-">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(1)" value="1">
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(2)" value="2">
<input type="button" onclick="numClick(3)" value="3">
<input type="button" onclick="operationClick('+')" value="+">
<br>

<input type="button" onclick="numClick(0)" value="0">
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="=">
<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a working sample of the suggestion given by Teemu. So credit there.
We add a focus event to our input controls and record the last `focused` control.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('#num1').addEventListener('focus', setLastElement);
  document.querySelector('#num2').addEventListener('focus', setLastElement);
});

var lastInputElement;
const setLastElement = (event) => {
  lastInputElement = event.target;
  console.log(event.target);
};

let activeElement = document.activeElement;

function numClick(number){
  if (lastInputElement === undefined) return;
  console.log("Num clicked=" + number);

  let tempNumber="";
  tempNumber = lastInputElement.value;
  tempNumber = tempNumber + number;
  activeElement.value=tempNumber;

}
```

```html
<input id = "num1" type="text" name="num1" value="">
  <span id="operacija"></span>
  <input id = "num2" type="text" name="num2" value="">
  <span>=</span>
  <span id="rezultat">0</span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="clearIt() "value="C">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('/')"value="/">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(7)" value="7">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(8)" value="8">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(9)" value="9">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('*')"value="*">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(4)" value="4">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(5)" value="5">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(6)" value="6">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('-')"value="-">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(1)" value="1">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(2)" value="2">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(3)" value="3">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('+')" value="+">
  <br>

  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(0)" value="0">
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="=">
  <br>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="zadatak1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to use **Jquery**, then you can try this code

```js
let activeElement = document.activeElement;

 var prevFocus;
    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
       prevFocus = $(this);
    });
    
function numClick(number){
 console.log("Num clicked=" + number);
  let tempNumber="";
  tempNumber = activeElement.value;
  tempNumber = tempNumber + number;
  activeElement.value=tempNumber;
  number= prevFocus.val() +''+ number
  prevFocus.val(number)
 prevFocus.focus()
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "num1" type="text" name="num1" value="">
  <span id="operacija"></span>
  <input id = "num2" type="text" name="num2" value="">
  <span>=</span>
  <span id="rezultat">0</span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="clearIt() "value="C">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('/')"value="/">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(7)" value="7">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(8)" value="8">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(9)" value="9">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('*')"value="*">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(4)" value="4">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(5)" value="5">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(6)" value="6">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('-')"value="-">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(1)" value="1">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(2)" value="2">
  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(3)" value="3">
  <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('+')" value="+">
  <br>

  <input type="button" onclick="numClick(0)" value="0">
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="=">
  <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sample code update. I have kept a track of the last focused on input and changed the text accordingly. I am guessing this is what you asked for. You can write the methods to control the value of the input fields accordingly.

```html
<!-- Added an extra method to remember the last focus, we pass the element as the function param:  -->
    <input id="num1" type="text" name="num1" value="" onclick='updateFocus(num1)'>
    <span id="operacija"></span>
    <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2" value="" onclick='updateFocus(num2)'>
    <span>=</span>
    <span id="rezultat">0</span>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="clearIt() " value="C">
    <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('/')" value="/">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(7)" value="7">
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(8)" value="8">
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(9)" value="9">
    <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('*')" value="*">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(4)" value="4">
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(5)" value="5">
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(6)" value="6">
    <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('-')" value="-">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(1)" value="1">
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(2)" value="2">
    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(3)" value="3">
    <input type="button" onclick="operationClick('+')" value="+">
    <br>

    <input type="button" onclick="numClick(0)" value="0">
    <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="=">
    <br>

    <script>
        var activeElement;

        // Updating the current focused on input field:
        function updateFocus(input) {
            activeElement = input;
            console.log("The active element is: +" + activeElement);
        }
        // Ensuring the number sent on click event is added to the current input box.
        function numClick(number) {
            // If a button pressed before focusing on any of the inputs:
            if (activeElement == null) return;
            
            console.log("Num clicked: " + number);
            
            var tempText = activeElement.value;
            tempText += number;
            activeElement.value = tempText;
        }
    </script>
```